# How can I change the size of scroll box(thumb) of a CScrollBar?

Tags: mfc, scrollbar

I can't find any method to change it. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The size of the scroll box is controlled by the range and page size of the scroll bar. You can use the [`CScrollBar::SetScrollInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/092c3690.aspx) function to control these settings, specifically the `nMin`, `nMax`, and `nPage` members of the [`SCROLLINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787537.aspx) structure.

You can find more information on scroll bars on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787527.aspx) in MSDN - read the "Scroll Box Position and Scrolling Range" section.

Comment: I'm quite sure it's called the truck size. But I could be wrong